# Mean vs Sum of cost in theano

Tags: machine-learning, python, theano

I have recently observed in many cases that taking mean of the cost function vs sum of cost function results in very different results (specifically in thenano)?

Many times sum of cost gives nan while taking mean resolves it. Why is this the case? Mean requires sum too, then what is the possible reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Perhaps the overflow occurs after the sum is cast into your variable's type, rather than during the calculation with internal variables? I think theano relies on numpy.

Comment: Obviously, the results are going to be different because the optimization process is updating the weights using $\partial W = \eta \times C$. One doing the average, you are using $C:=C/N$. Equivalently, you could also do $\eta:=\eta/N$, where $\eta$ is the learning rate. But if you divide one but not the other, obviously weights are being updated differently.

Comment: Agreed, but why does the result changes so drastically in both cases? I mean with sum sometimes cost comes out to be nan, and with mean it comes out to be normal.